# RJDBC Error When Trying to Connect to Hive Server: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Invalid method name: 'execute'

Tags: r, jdbc, hadoop, hive, rjdbc

I have been trying to use RJDBC package to connect R(on local machine) with Hive(server), and am seeing errors:

**Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Invalid method name: 'execute'**

I directly copied the jars that's running on the server to my local machine, which then shouldn't be the problem with the driver versions. I also tried to use earlier versions of RJDBC package, but it didn't work, neither.

I would really appreciate any ideas/suggestions.

My script:

#

hive_connection <- function( hostname, port, lib_dir, hive_jars){
  library(RJDBC)
  library(DBI)
  library(rJava)
  library(Rserve)

# lib_dir: directory containing the jars & drivers
  hive_class_path <- file.path( lib_dir, hive_jars )

drv <- JDBC( 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver',  classPath=  hive_class_path, "`" )
  server <- sprintf( 'jdbc:hive://%s:%s', hostname, port )

return ( dbConnect( drv, server, 'hive','hive') )
}

conn <- hive_connection('hostname',9083,'lib_dir', list.files('lib_dir'))

Answer (score 0):

This is related to driver and port, i was facing same error while connecting hive with jdbc driver. finally i find out right driver and hive service with port. it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try
 `drv <- JDBC( 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver',c(hive_class_path ,pattern="jar$" ,full.names=T) )`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue by following two steps -

Change 1:

```
drv <- JDBC( 'org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver', classPath= hive_class_path, "`" )
```

The change is in the driver, notice I took out .hadoop

Change 2:

```
server <- sprintf( 'jdbc:hive2://%s:%s', hostname, port )
```

I added "2" in the url for connection, to connect to hiveServer2.

I got the detailed explanation by reading this - http://jayunit100.blogspot.com/2013/12/the-anatomy-of-jdbc-connection-in-hive.html